# Err Unknown command scan, redis-cli

Tags: redis, ubuntu-18.04

Installed the redis on ubuntu using 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04

redis-server -v gives

```
Redis server v=4.0.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=76095d16786fbcba
```

redis-cli -v gives

```
redis-cli 4.0.9
```

While redis-cli info gives

```
redis_version:2.4.6
redis_git_sha1:26cdd13a
redis_git_dirty:0
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:winsock2
gcc_version:4.6.1
```

When run the scan command **redis-cli scan 0** it gives error

```
(error) ERR unknown command 'scan'
```

Learned that scan only works on redis version 2.8+, so tried to update redis **sudo apt install redis-server** but it says

```
redis-server is already the newest version (5:4.0.9-1ubuntu0.1).
```

How can we run the SCAN command?

Comment: From the output of info command, you're using *Redis 2.4.6*. You need a newer version.

Comment: but in install redis-server it says already a newest version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with your previous version of Cli: https://redis.io/commands/scan

upgrade your cli version to 2.8.0 or higher

I got the same issue due to install redis(2.4.0) on window 10 and donwload ubuntu from windows store and install latest version of redis(5.0.2) in Ubuntu but still redis-cli showed 2.4.6

To resolve this problem just uninstall redis-server from window and restart redis-server on Ubuntu